# Performing actions on my desktop causes it to crash

Tags: 18.04, kubuntu, desktop-environments

Today when I started it up laptop I had the default Kubuntu wallpaper (I had a different wallpaper and it booted to that). I thought it was odd so I right clicked to get to the desktop settings and I clicked on 'Configure Desktop' when I did it seemed like my entire desktop crashed. I did not get any error messages but my entire screen went black and I could not see my panels or my desktop - I am still able to see my open windows. I force booted my laptop again and tried deleting a file off my desktop and the same thing occurred. I decided to try to update to see if I was missing any updates and I noticed that Discover was no longer installed (I did not uninstall it). I believe I accidentally broke some packages when I was trying to install something previously but I don't remember what it was and I don't know what to do to check/fix this. Thank you in advance.

**Specs:**

- OS: Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS x86_64
- Host: XPS 13 9343
- Kernel: 4.15.0-38-generic
- DE: KDE
- Terminal: konsole
- CPU: Intel i7-5600U (4) @ 3.200GHz
- GPU: Intel HD Graphics 5500

**Edit:**

This seems to be an issue with the plasmashell crashing, once it had crashed I ran it again via the command line and caused the error again and I got a seg fault from it (I removed some of the repeated stuff):

```
org.kde.plasmaquick: Applet preload policy set to 1
Connecting to deprecated signal QDBusConnectionInterface::serviceOwnerChanged(QString,QString,QString)
Trying to use rootObject before initialization is completed, whilst using setInitializationDelayed. Forcing completion
KActivities: Database connection:  "kactivities_db_resources_140558459253184_readonly" 
    query_only:          QVariant(qlonglong, 1) 
    journal_mode:        QVariant(QString, "wal") 
    wal_autocheckpoint:  QVariant(qlonglong, 100) 
    synchronous:         QVariant(qlonglong, 0)
Entry is not valid "applications:org.kde.discover.desktop" 0x556ab435d1b0
Entry is not valid "applications:org.kde.discover.desktop" 0x556ab435d1b0
Closing SQL connection:  "kactivities_db_resources_140558459253184_readonly"
KActivities: Database connection:  "kactivities_db_resources_140558459253184_readonly" 
    query_only:          QVariant(qlonglong, 1) 
    journal_mode:        QVariant(QString, "wal") 
    wal_autocheckpoint:  QVariant(qlonglong, 100) 
    synchronous:         QVariant(qlonglong, 0)
Nothing to load - the client id is empty
Nothing to load - the client id is empty

org.kde.plasma: requesting config for "Panel" without a containment!
QCoreApplication::postEvent: Unexpected null receiver
file:///usr/share/plasma/plasmoids/org.kde.desktopcontainment/contents/ui/FolderItemDelegate.qml:355:34: Unable to assign [undefined] to bool

Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Answer (score 1):

This turned out to be an issue with the Active-window plasmoid, once I got rid of that everything else started working normally.